GATconv issue edge_index that are larger than
enter image description here
I can't find out what my fault is.
I tried to make heterodata (geometric), and I want to install one centre 'target' node and several neighbours, so I made edge_index below.
sub_lee.index:tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3])
sub_lee.validation shows me 'True'

but an error happened:
"edge_index that is larger than 0 (got 3)"
so I can't figure out what causes problems.
